# nodejs and pg module - query syntax

Tags: node.js

I'm using nodejs 0.10.12 and the pg module, version 2.2.0.

Now, on the server side I have a code like

```
var ja=message.utf8Data;
var query = client.query("SELECT pins.p_name FROM pins WHERE  p_id = ja");
```

`ja` is a var, representing an int,came from the client side, through websockets. I'm trying to use it to the query but I can not. I can not find the right syntax to make it work. The query and the code in general work fine, if I replace `ja` in the query with , for example, 64. 
I tried syntax like `p_id=(ja)` but I keep getting errors like `undefiend` or `ja is not a column in a table`.

What is the rigth syntax?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.query("SELECT pins.p_name FROM pins WHERE p_id ="+ja);
```

Should do the trick.  Since it's coming in over a socket you might want to do some sanitization of the input to prevent injection attacks.  The mysql-node module has a good function for that

```
  connection.escape()
```

Or alternatively,

```
connection.query('SELECT ? FROM myTable',[ja],function(err,rows) {});
```